# C# Backup: Backup Failed for Server XXX

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, backup

I have this code to Backup My database using C#.

But I get `Backup Failed for Server ADMIN-PC` error message.

I can run Backup from SQL Server Management Studio but from here for some reason it gives me this error.

How can I make this work?

```csharp
private void btnBackup_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        progressBar1.Value = 0;

        try
        {
            Server dbServer = new Server(new ServerConnection(txtServer.Text, txtUserName.Text, txtPassword.Text));
            Backup dbBackup = new Backup() {Action = BackupActionType.Database, Database = txtDatabase.Text};
            dbBackup.Devices.AddDevice(@"C:\PDM.bak", DeviceType.File);
            dbBackup.Initialize = true;
            dbBackup.PercentComplete += DbBackup_PercentComplete;
            dbBackup.PercentComplete += DbBackup_Complete;
            dbBackup.SqlBackupAsync(dbServer);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Message ", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);


        }

    }
    private void DbBackup_Complete(object sender, ServerMessageEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Error != null)
        {
            label5.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
            {
                lblStatus.Text = e.Error.Message;
            });
        }

    }
    private void DbBackup_PercentComplete(object sender, PercentCompleteEventArgs e)
    {
        progressBar1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
        {
            progressBar1.Value = e.Percent;
            progressBar1.Update();


        });
        label5.Text = $"{e.Percent}%";
    }
}
```

Comment: Check whether the exception you get has an inner exception with more details

Answer (score 1):

Is that the all exception message? Try only the backup work without progressbar and see what exception is thrown. Without full picture, people here cannot help you enough.

Do you only have to use that way for backup ?

This is my code to backup database for your reference.

```
using (SqlConnection masterdbConn = new SqlConnection())
{
     masterdbConn.ConnectionString = localmasterConnectionString;
     masterdbConn.Open();

      using (SqlCommand rollback_dbcomm = new SqlCommand())
      {
           rollback_dbcomm.Connection = masterdbConn;
           rollback_dbcomm.CommandText = "ALTER DATABASE mydbname SET MULTI_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE";

           rollback_dbcomm.ExecuteNonQuery();
      }
      masterdbConn.Close();
}

SqlConnection.ClearAllPools();

using (SqlConnection backupConn = new SqlConnection())
{
     backupConn.ConnectionString = localConnectionString;
     backupConn.Open();

     using (SqlCommand backupcomm = backupConn.CreateCommand())
     {
          backupcomm.CommandText = @"BACKUP DATABASE mydbname TO DISK='c:\mydbname.bak'";

          backupcomm.ExecuteNonQuery();
     }
     backupConn.Close();
 }
```

Alter DATABASE ROLL BACK IMMEDIATE command finishes all the unfinished transactions with the database and let's say 'hands off from the database to be ready for Backup.

And you need to check roles and permissions in the connectionstring..

Can you show the SQL syntax to backup in SQL Server Management Studio? and the connectionstring without the credentials(like password)?
And can you describe you problem in more detail?

Backup work needs deep understanding how Sever works..

Comment: that works Thanks! but how can i get the progress bar to work?

Comment: That's good. I've tried implement with SMO like you at this time again. And I've realized I also tried this SMO way years ago but gave up(failed) because of DLL issues and changed to the way of my above answer. Did it take long time to complete the backup? How big is the database size? If it doesn't take long time and it's not big database, just indeterminate progressBar would be enough and you can find many progressBar solution through Nuget or Github.

Comment: no its very quick,the database size very small and i would like to add current data and time in the backup file name

Comment: My database is hundreds MB size but still very quick, almost immediately. If you're similar with my case, I think progressbar is meaningless in real world. Only simple, pretty messagebox would be enough or as I said indeterminate progressbar should be ok because it's too short time to display the progress. I also add the date of backup in the file name and it's easy. You can find many examples by searching.